# Partial match of enum variants

Tags: rust

Let's assume this code:

```rust
pub enum Operations {
    Nop,
    Read,
    Write { content: Vec<u8> },
}

pub fn do_operation(op: Operations) {
    match op {
        Operations::Nop => {}
        rest => {
            // open a file
            match rest {
                Operations::Read => {
                    // read file
                }
                Operations::Write { .. } => {
                    // write file
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have three variants, where in two I'd like to do similar operations (in this case open a file and do something with it).
But with the third variant I want to do a operation, that doesn't involve opening the file at all.

Currently rust refuses to compile this code:

```
error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `Nop` not covered
  --> src/lib.rs:12:19
   |
1  | / pub enum Operations {
2  | |     Nop,
   | |     --- not covered
3  | |     Read,
4  | |     Write { content: Vec<u8> },
5  | | }
   | |_- `Operations` defined here
...
12 |               match rest {
   |                     ^^^^ pattern `Nop` not covered
   |
   = help: ensure that all possible cases are being handled, possibly by adding wildcards or more match arms
   = note: the matched value is of type `Operations`
```

IMHO it should be detectable by the compiler that `Operations::Nop` isn't possible anymore.

Is there a way to make this work, e.g. by activating a nightly feature or using a workaround? Is there an open issue at github which already suggests this kind of partial matching?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, though why don't you simply match on `Operations::Read | Operations::Write`?

Comment: You can add `_ => unreachable!()` in your second match.

Comment: @IInspectable you mean something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=babc585120de702b637fb996a638bc58 ?

Comment: @Jmb true, one workaround. Not a nice one tbh :)

Comment: Indeed, although I missed that those enums have different variants, so that won't work.

Comment: Can you eliminate `Nop` from your enum and pass an `Option<Operations>` instead (i.e. basically transform `Nop` to `None`)?

Comment: Sadly not. The operations are sent via JSON from a website and taking `None` as value doesn't make any sense in the API

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible; Rust doesn't do the sort of type narrowing that Typescript or Swift do.

Your best alternatives are:

- Use `=> unreachable!()`. It's annoying but not a big deal in the long run (especially since the optimizer will trivially notice that the branch is unreachable and omit it from the compiled code)
- Refactor your `enum` to reflect the nested behavior you want, or consider using an `Option` to contain your `Nop` variant:

```rust
enum Operation {
    Noop,
    FileOperation(FileOperation),
}

enum FileOperation {
    Read,
    Write { content: Vec<u8> },
}

fn do_operation(op: Operation) {
    match op {
        Nop => { ... },
        FileOperation(file_op) => {
            // open a file
            match file_op => { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Between these two, I'd probably recommend just doing unreachable, especially if (as I assume is the case) your actual `Operation` enum is much larger than the sample code you've shown here.